# How to seriazed Tm Extra Product Options Order Data while exporting using WP All Export Plugin

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, plugins

I am using TM Extra Product Options for adding custom/extra product options for orders. Here is my product page picture: 
[image]

I also used WP All Export plugin for export order data.

During export I have this option by default: 
[image]

and my output in excel preview is as follows: 
[image]

I added a code to serialized data and the code is

```
function data_deserialize($value) { 
    $output = ''; 
    $data = maybe_unserialize($value); $data = $data[0]; 
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $output .= $key.': '.$value.'';
}
return $output;
}
```

After this the my Excel preview: 
[image]

I only want my Excel display Enter Your Mobile Model + The value added my customer. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer :)

```
<?php 
function tm_wpallexport_data($value) { 
    $output = ''; 
    $epos = maybe_unserialize($value); 
    if (is_array($epos) ){
        foreach ($epos as $key => $epo) {
            if ($epo && is_array($epo)){
                $output .= $epo['name'] .': '. $epo['value'] .'<br>';
        }
    }
    }

    return $output;
}
?>
```

If it help someone please share in comments.